# I need help to selecting a button from an array of buttons using material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So things are like this, I have an array of phone numbers, it's mapped so everynumber has a button to copy the number and make a call. Thing is, we use material-ui, specifically the v4 of it.

What i need to do is that whenever someone clicks a button this button change it's color to idk green let's say so the worker knows they are using that button, avoiding clicking again and those kind of things.

material-ui has it's own way to put a color to the button using the color prop and the createTheme API, is there ANY way to do this using &:active or &:selected in material with the createTheme API, is there a way to do it without it (it's not mandatory to use createTheme).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you need the button to remain "green," or is it just while its being pressed?

Comment: I need the button to remain green until another button is clicked, sorry I missed that point. For now I oonly have a tooltip but it vanishes after a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering your buttons using a map, store the index of the button that is clicked in some state, and use it to compare the index of the current button with that stored index, if matches change the color

something like:

```
export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {buttons.map((button, idx) => {
        const isActive = active === idx;
        return (
          <Button
            key={`btn-${idx}`}
            onClick={() => setActive(idx)}
            variant="contained"
            color={isActive ? "success" : "primary"}
          >
            {button}
          </Button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```